# The first occurence of the first two columns

Tags: awk, sort, columns

I've got this file:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
aaa.bbb.eee.ccc
ggg.hhh.jjj.kkk
fff.uuu.yyy.ddd
eee.rrr.ddd.bbb
eee.rrr.www.zzz
eee.rrr.sss.nnn
eee.rrr.qqq.kkk
```

I want to filter it so it displays the whole line only when the first occurrence of the first two columns happens.

The expected output is:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
ggg.hhh.jjj.kkk
fff.uuu.yyy.ddd
eee.rrr.ddd.bbb
```

So far what I could do was:

```
cat file |awk -F"." '{print $1"."$2}' |uniq -c
```

but it only shows the first first two columns and the number of repetitions.

Comment: if order is not important... `sort -t. -k1,2 -u file` and if total characters for first two columns is same... `uniq -w7 file`

Comment: `awk -F. '!seen[$1""$2]++' file`